# Adding a class with styling does nothing - NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am currently trying to learn NextJS and I've decided to go with a simple weather api that collects data from given city. I've learnt some new stuff and I really like it so far. There is however one issue that I can't seem to solve and that would be adding a class with styling.

Now... Given the GIF below, you can see it DOES add the class when location is being typed but the styling does not change.
https://gyazo.com/55be0759cc8cc514905a7a661274f73c

The 'Home_main__1Z1aG' should change its height and font-size when I add the class but it doesnt. I've never experienced this before and I've made sure that I am targeting the correct div.

I use state to add the class to the 'Home_main__1Z1aG' div.

```
<main className={`${styles.main} ${searchedCity ? 'loc_set' : ''}`}>
     <input value={searchedCity} placeholder="City, Country" className={styles.title} onChange={e => setSearchedCity(e.target.value)} />
</main>
```

My styling:

```
.loc_set {
  height: 10vh;

  .title {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
```

One important thing to mention is that I've added SCSS to my project.

I think that I need to somehow render the whole div since it is serverside rendered, but am I thinking wrong or? I've basically tried moving my styling around to make sure nesting wasnt an issue, I've made sure that the class is correctly named etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components in Next.js use CSS modules. Assuming that the HTML you've provided is in a component and not a page, you'll have to reference it using imports.

```
<main className={`${styles.main} ${searchedCity ? styles.locSet : ''}`}>
     <input value={searchedCity} placeholder="City, Country" className={styles.title} onChange={e => setSearchedCity(e.target.value)} />
</main>
```

I am not sure if `_` would work, so maybe change that to a hyphenated classname.

```
.loc-set {
  height: 10vh;

  .title {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. styles.loc_set worked. I thought that you were allowed to do it like i did but React/next handles stuff different than what I am used to (php). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ampersand:

```
.loc_set {
  height: 10vh;

  & .title {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
```